# setOpenGlDrawCallback how to resize OpenCV window

Tags: opengl, opencv, glut

I'm drawing on a window using

```
    namedWindow("windowName",CV_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    setOpenGlDrawCallback("windowName",glCallback);
```

The window is displayed but with wrong dimensions and i've no idea about how resize/set the right size

UPDATE:
i've modified the code just like the example **point_cloud.cpp** in samples/cpp/ but i can't set the window size

Answer (score 2):

You might try:

```
namedWindow("windowName", CV_WINDOW_OPENGL | CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
setOpenGlDrawCallback("windowName", glCallback);
```

Or:

```
namedWindow("windowName", CV_WINDOW_OPENGL);
resizeWindow("windowName", 400, 300);
setOpenGlDrawCallback("windowName", glCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Studying (better) the example provided i figure out my error, 
this is the correct code:

```
namedWindow(windowName,CV_WINDOW_OPENGL | CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
resizeWindow(windowName, 640, 480);
setOpenGlDrawCallback(windowName, glutDisplay);
for( ; ; )
{
 updateWindow(windowName);
 //etc etc
}
```

Comment: In other words, my answer was correct. Instead of adding one of your own you should consider accepting the answer that solved the problem.